# Angular: Keep state of component on back navigation but also reset it

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm new to Angular and have a requirement regarding routing between components.
The app consists of 3 components:

```
component_a -> component _b -> component_c
```

In `component_b` there is a list which can be filtered and sorted. When I navigate from `component_b` to `component_c` (detail view) and back again (via browser back) the list should be filtered and sorted based on the already entered values.
However, if I navigate from `component_a` to `component_b`, the filters and sorters should be reset.

The filters and sorters are stored in a service, so they are read and applied again when navigating back from `component_c` to `component_b`.
To reset the filters/sorters when starting from `component_a`, a state is passed via the route, which triggers the reset.

`component_a`

```
this.router.navigate(["component_b"], {state: {reset: true}});
```

`component_b`

```
if (window.history.state?.reset) {
   this.reset();
}
```

Unfortunately, the behavior is now also such that when from `component_c` is navigated back to `component_b` via browser back, this state is still present and the filters/sorters are incorrectly deleted.
I already tried it with adding the filters/sorters to the url as query params. But since the filters can get very complex, this solution is not practical for me.

How could I implement this requirement correctly?

Comment: When component-c leaves then onDestroy hook will fire, you can use that hook to filter the value same to component-b when coming from c to b

Answer (score 0):

1. If **component_a** (when the parent component is **component_a** )  loaded before **component_b**, when navigating back from **component_c** to **component_b** , then state is passed to **component_a**. Then state will be lost when **component_b** is loading.

State is lost when reloading/loading another component before the navigation

If that's the case try to pass the state again from the **component_a**

2. Use `this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.reset` to read the state

   ```
   constructor(private router: Router) {
       if(this.router.getCurrentNavigation() !== undefined) {
           if(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras !== undefined) {
             if(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state !== undefined) {
                 if(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.reset) {
                    this.reset();
                 }
             }
           }
       }
   }
   ```